# ¿Porqué no puedo realizar un UPDATE sobre la misma columna de identificación desde un SP en SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedure, where

Hola buenas tardes estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado en donde yo pueda actualizar la misma columna de donde se valida el WHERE; este es mi código:

```
UPDATE CUPS_DETALLES SET CODIGO_CUPS = 'PQ998702' WHERE 
CODIGO_CUPS='PQ998702-1' AND NUMERO_CONTRATO='2000100005775'
```

El problema no es en crear el SP; el inconveniente es que el SP se ejecuta pero no actualiza el mismo campo donde hago el WHERE. Aqui va el codigo de mi SP:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[CUPS_DETALLES_ACTUALIZAR]
@NUMEROCONTRATO VARCHAR (50), @CUPSNUEVO VARCHAR (50),@CUPSVIEJO VARCHAR (50)
AS
UPDATE CUPS_DETALLES
SET CODIGO_CUPS = @CUPSNUEVO
WHERE CODIGO_CUPS=@CUPSVIEJO AND NUMERO_CONTRATO=@NUMEROCONTRATO
```

Si se dan cuenta el campo que quiero Setear es el mismo campo en donde estoy validando la clausula WHERE.

En una consulta normal me funciona, pero cuando la paso a un SP me dice que los campos se completaron correctamente pero no hace el UPDATE.

Alguien que me ayude, gracias.

Comment: Creas el SP y cuando lo ejecutas qué error te sale? O no puedes crear el SP?

Comment: agregue el SP para poder ver que podría estar mal

Comment: El procedimiento ya está creado? Es decir: usas `ALTER PROC` (yo siempre utilizo `ALTER PROCEDURE`, no estoy seguro que `ALTER PROC` sea válido). Si el SP no esta creado debes crearlo con `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `ALTER` es para modificar uno creado previamente.

Comment: Si ya el procedimiento esta creado.

Comment: Podrias poner talvez unos datos de ejemplo, podria ser error humano, ya que el sp lo veo normal

Comment: @Liyo Si, ya el procedimiento esta creado. Lee mi pregunta ahí esta claro que es lo que quiero hacer con el SP.

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Lo que busco es actualizar el campo CODIGO_CUPS pero ese mismo campo también lo uso en el WHERE.

Comment: Digamos que mi CODIGO_CUPS tiene el valor 100 y quiero actualizarlo después a 200 pero para actualizarlo, el mismo campo lo quiero utilizar en la clausula where para buscar en el mismo campo CODIGO_CUPS.

Comment: Si no debes de tener problema eso se puede hacer y como te digo como lo tienes esta bien, te decia si podrias agregar unos ejemplos para mostrarte

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Otro ejemplo: `UPDATE CUPS_DETALLES SET CODIGO_CUPS = '200' WHERE 
CODIGO_CUPS='100' AND NUMERO_CONTRATO='2000100005775'` en esta consulta común funciona pero en un SP no.

Comment: Mira te anexo un ejemplo para que veas lo que te digo https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f8774d2717b18f909e5acb5b4458cf2

Comment: Basándome en el BDFiddle del compañero @EdgarVazquez, puedo ver que si está bien tu SP, incluso la lógica, debe haber un dato extra que estás considerando. Por como está, debería funcionar correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Ya pude resolver mi problema mediante un trigger como el siguiente:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_UP_CUPSDETALLES]

ON [dbo].[CUPS] FOR UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @NUEVOCUPS VARCHAR (50)
DECLARE @CUPSVIEJO VARCHAR (50)
DECLARE @NUMERO_CONTRATOACTUAL VARCHAR (100)

SELECT @CUPSVIEJO = CODIGO_CUPS FROM DELETED
SELECT @NUMERO_CONTRATOACTUAL = NUMERO_CONTRATO FROM DELETED
SELECT @NUEVOCUPS = CODIGO_CUPS FROM INSERTED

UPDATE CUPS_DETALLES SET CODIGO_CUPS = @NUEVOCUPS WHERE 
CODIGO_CUPS=@CUPSVIEJO AND NUMERO_CONTRATO=@NUMERO_CONTRATOACTUAL
```

Gracias a todos por contribuir a este problema, son geniales todos.

El inconveniente anterior probablemente se refería que al momento de realizar el UPDATE sobre el mismo campo WHERE el SQL no encontraba el código porque ya este estaba actualizado.

Es decir que yo le decía "Actualízame el campo CODIGO_CUPS a 200 en donde ese mismo campo CODIGO_CUPS sea igual 100"

Al momento del SP buscar ese código 100 en el campo CODIGO_CUPS ya no lo encontraba porque este ya se había actualizado sobre si mismo a 200.

Entonces la solución fue realizar un trigger en donde este me toma los datos antiguos de ese código antes de ser actualizados por medio de la tabla temporal DELETED y así poder realizar el UPDATE sobre el mismo campo de validación WHERE.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente su funcionamiento: ten en cuenta que la respuesta debe ser útil no solo para ti, sino también para otros que tengan el mismo inconveniente más adelante. Puede que estos no comprendan lo que hace el trigger. Lee [answer], y no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.